# jQuery slider go back to front slider when reached end of slider?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) slider go back to front slider when reached end of slider?

Process:
I load an HTML on a div with Ajax when it reaches the end of slider scroll.

I want the slider to go back to front (starting point) when the process above executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your slider initialization code, there's an available `slide` event:

```
$('.selector').slider({
  //Current stuff...
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    if($(this).slider('option','max') === ui.value) {
      $(this).slider('option','value',$(this).slider('option','min'));
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

When reaching max value, reset to min value, `return false;` cancels the slide so the reset can take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) and [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) functions to set the position of the scrollbar in your AJAX callback.